# Are questions about animations or comics inspired by Japanese culture or styles considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Examples include [Avatar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0417299/), [Korra](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1695360/) and, to some extent, [Samurai Jack](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0278238/). They're all widely popular American cartoons, sometimes even referred to as *[Amerime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime-influenced_animation)*.

Are questions about these series on-topic?

Comment: This question should be broadended to manga, with manga-like cartoons like Dreamland, which is from France and is even *drawn* manga-style, as in, right-to-left reading, IIRC. Same goes for Manwha and Manhua.

Comment: I agree with @Xeo -- we might need to extend this conversation to include manhwa. I love *Bride of the Water God* but I'm not sure if asking questions about it would be on topic here.

Answer (score 7):

Tough, I also had thoughts about it. I believe that by definition, we should *not* allow such cartoons, because we need to draw the line.

The line should be drawn at "Anime & Manga only", which by definition is only Japanese.

Comment: I tend to agree, a line has to be drawn. On MyAnimeList.net, Avatar has been allowed for only a brief amount of time, IIRC. The same goes for the French "manga" Dreamland, which has been removed recently.

Comment: I agree with this, ***however*** I believe manhwa and manhua should be on topic here. I've mentioned as much in my answer below.

Comment: How do you define Japanese? TLoK has some episodes animated by Japanese companies http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Legend_of_Korra_episodes#Book_Two:_Spirits_.282013.29 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierrot_(company)

Comment: @BLCL: That's a very good, but a somewhat separate question. I've personally come to the conclusion that the best indicator I can think of so far is whether the original audio is in Japanese or not. For the specific (intentionally far-fetched, I assume) example of Avatar/TLoK being Japanese animation, I think it's pretty obvious to anyone that the decision to use a Japanese studio for some of the episodes in the second season of a sequel does not make the whole franchise/series Japanese/anime.

Answer (score 2):

I recently watched a Youtube video where an American asked some Japanese people what their favorite manga and anime were. One girl answered that SpongeBob was her favorite "anime".

It seems to me that Japanese people don't make the distinction between western cartoons and anime like we do. Therefore I'd rather be on the permissive side when it comes to which content is allowed or not.

On the other hand, I do strongly feel that there must be at least some Japanese influence to the show. Otherwise this site might just as well be called the Cartoons and Comics SE.

Comment: Which then bleeds into my site of Movies & TV SE :P

Comment: I'd like to take this opportunity to plug my [Comics & Sequential Art proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47733/comics-sequential-art), then!

Comment: Just to clarify, anime-style drawing is or isn't enough to conclude Japanese influence then?

Comment: There's a reason for that. In English we have the words "animation" and "cartoon" to denote any and all animation. (Ditto for other languages) In Japanese, "anime" is that word, and just means "animation" - so the described response was completely understandable. The word anime was loaned from the Japanese language to western languages because western people wanted a word specifically for Japanese animation. So even though the word used is the same, the meaning of the word is very different in western languages compared to the Japanese language.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Korra/ATLA and Samurai Jack and anime-inspired *Western* shows should be disallowed.

However, I do feel that manhwa *should* be on topic. A lot of manhwa / manhua looks just like doujinshi or independent manga.

To clarify: I *don't* think anything that "looks like" manga should be on topic here. However, manhua and manhwa are the products of Japan's historical dominance of East Asia, both economically/politically and culturally.

Comment: Although manhwa / manhua, from what I saw, are generally left-to-right, not right-to-left reading. And if we go by looks, Dreamland would fit just perfectly. It's a manga written in French, really.

Comment: They have strong cultural ties to Japanese media, though, thanks to both Japan's economic and military strength historically as well as the sheer prevalence of Japanese media in East Asia. Japan is to East Asia as America is to most of the "West".

Comment: So basically it counts if the average person would mistake it for Anime / Manga, then?

Comment: @RachelKeslensky That strikes me has an intense reduction of the larger cultural factors that have led to manhua / manhwa. It's not just "would a bunch of *gaijin* think it's manga" -- it's also about the strength of Japanese cultural influence.

Comment: So do you want to include OEL Manga, then? I'd think you'd have a hard time saying one belongs but not the other.

Comment: So you consider TLoK to not have strong ties to japanese media despite having some episodes animated by Pierrot (I'm assuming that lack of strong ties is your reason for disallowing) ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierrot_(company)